# Cómo pasar valor de Javascript a PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

tengo un input tipo date que el cliente ingresa una fecha ahora con esa fecha q se registra
necesito hacer una consulta abajo mostrando las salas disponible.

```
<label for="Fecha">Fecha :</label>
<input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha" class="campo_chico">
```

aqui mas abajo tendre una tabla donde mostraria los campos ingresado en esa fecha mi consulta sql es:

```
$turnTabla = mysqli_query($conSanatorio, "SELECT q.Descripcion, tq.Quirofano
AND tq.Fecha = '2020-06-26'  **<---- remplazar aqui la fecha obtenida con el input**
AND tq.Quirofano = 14
GROUP BY tq.numero");
```

todo esto esta en la misma pagina se que se hacce con jquery pero nose hacerlo o no lo entiendo. alguien podría ayudarme? o guiarme como hacerlo

Comment: Amigo te sale mucho mejor y mas facil trabajar con un <input type="date' name="nDate">

Comment: como? seria soy nuevo experimentando con esto.

Comment: Mira mi respuesta, y me comentas que tal

Comment: El problema es que desde HTML no estas mandando el dato, tienes que poner un `<form>`, apuntar a tu archivo de PHP y enviar la información. Es rudimentario pero funciona, hay cosas más sofisticadas como AJAX, si quieres que el HTML se conecte por arte de magia con el backend, jamás sucederá. cómo se llama el archivo que tiene esta query?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo suponiendo que en tu base de datos tienes registros con fecha como estos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tu input debería ser de tipo date, para que el usuario pueda seleccionar una fecha en vez de tener que escribirla:

```
<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" class="campo_chico">
```

Una consulta para traer los datos de una fecha especifica (Tomando como ejemplo mi tabla) seria de la forma:

```
SELECT * FROM program_authorization_data WHERE dateCreate = '2022-01-12';
```

Ahora para pasarle como dato el input del usuario debes capturarlo en una variable y se lo pasas asi:

```
$date = $_POST['fecha']; //Fecha ingresada por el usuario
SELECT * FROM program_authorization_data WHERE dateCreate = '$date'; //Consulta
```

Y el resultado seria este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: claro asi pero como lo capturo asi numas como lo pusite.
<?php date =$_post['fecha']>
no uso nada de ajax o cosas por el stilo ?

porq es eso lo q necesito lo q acabas de hacer.

Comment: <label for="Fecha">Fecha :</label>
        <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" class="campo_chico">
        <?php $date = $_POST['fecha']; 
                echo "valor".$date
        ?>

lo hice asi y me da error.

Comment: Cerraron la pregunta, que error tienes ? ya lo solucionaste ?

Comment: no amigo sin poder solucionarlo. es justo eso lo q vos tiene lo q ncesito pero no lo puedo hacer. :(

Comment: Haz la pregunta otra vez pero un poco mas elaborada te recomiendo que uses: https://www.db-fiddle.com/ , para mostrar lo que intentas y que resultado obtienes bro.